# Mysql trigger send via post a value after insert in table to php file

Tags: php, mysql, file, triggers, insert

I would like to know how to send via post a value after insert in table to php file using Mysql trigger.

Greetings.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: After finished a phone call, I want to send a post action to php file to update more information.

Answer (score 0):

I think mysql trigger is database object that will be activated when we run one of mysql statement like INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE and it cannot send a value to php file. CMIIW.

Comment: you're welcome. if you got something new about it (may be i missed) please share it..:)